# How to add dynamic parameter to url on Mailchimp?

Tags: mailchimp

I need to redirect users after subscribing to "Confirmation thank you page" on my own site. 
It must looks like this 
mysite.com/*|COUPONCODE|*

But merge tag don't compiling and attached to url as static text.Is it possible on mailchimp? Thank you for replies!

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add the asterisks:

```
https://example.com/*|COUPONCODE|*
```

[Here](http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/design/create-unique-urls-for-subscribers) is the doc for customized URL.

Comment: Sorry, asterisks cuted by stackoverflow, i dont forgot them.

Comment: Sorry, asterisks cuted by stackoverflow, i dont forgot them.  Instructions of doc works for campaigns but for redirects on Confirmation thank you page don't working. I logged requests for my site and logs shows me next GET-request > https://example.com/*|COUPONCODE|*

Comment: Could you include the exact content of the HTML you're putting in your newsletter?

Comment: There no newsletter, only redirect url. I need to change url here > Lists > Signup forms > Confirmation thank you page > url. What url i need to put in form?